# How to display an attribute of a Json in a res.send()

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, api, post

I am working on an API developing project, and I am having a difficulties. I want to display after a creation (POST) only one of the attributes (I would like to only display the tittle of the new book created), like this.

```
   title: 'Lorien Legacies'
```

The method that I have for post is the following:

```
//CREATE Request Handler
app.post('/api/books', (req, res)=> {

const { error } = validateBook(req.body);
 if (error){
  res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message)
   return;
 }
 const book = {
  id: books.length + 1,
  title: req.body.title
 };
books.push(book);
res.send(book);
});
```

Comment: `res.send({title:book.title});` ?

Comment: Thank you my friend!!!

Comment: Have added the same as answer. You can close by accepting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
res.send({title : book.title});
```